# microsoft excel cannot access the file there are several possible reasons + Workbooks.Open +

Tags: c#, excel, interopservices

In my C#.net application, I am creating excel file and it is working fine at my local system but its give below error when deployed the application in IIS

- My Web server don't have office installed.

Error:

ExceptionMessage>
Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '\............xltm'. There are several possible reasons: 
• The file name or path does not exist. 
• The file is being used by another program. 
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: you mention workbooks.open in the title, how is that involved here?

Comment: This is line: WB = xApp.Workbooks.Open(oTemplate.ToString(), missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

Comment: **DON'T** use Office interop on a web server. For starters, you'd need to buy a separate license for *every* user. Second, if you're careless you'd end up opening a new Excel instance for each request, quickly exhausting all RAM. Even if you're carefull, you're creating a new instance for each concurrent request which wastes a *lot* of RAM. And you'd still have to pay for all of them

Comment: Web applications use libraries like Epplus to generate real `xlsx` files instead without using Excel. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files in a well-defined format, which means you could just creates the files on the fly. Epplus though makes this a *lot* easier, as easy as eg `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection()`